# Given the set $\mathfrak{B} = ((1,2,0)^{\top}, (2,1,2)^{\top}, (3,1,1)^{\top})$ that is a basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

a) Find the coordinate vector of the vector $v = (1, 2, 3)^{\top}$ relative to this basis

b) Let $\mathfrak{B}' = ((0,1,0)^{\top} , (1,0,1)^{\top}, (2,1,0)^{\top})$. Find the matrix P that describes the transition from $\mathfrak{B}$ to $\mathfrak{B}'$

---

a) Finding the coordinate vector relative to this basis means solving the system
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\
    x_2 \\
    x_3
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    3
\end{bmatrix}$$

After solving the system https://matrixcalc.org/slu.html#solve-using-Gaussian-elimination%28%7B%7B1,2,3,1%7D,%7B2,1,1,2%7D,%7B0,2,1,3%7D%7D%29

We get the vector $x = \begin{bmatrix}
    4/7 \\
    15/7 \\
    -9/7
\end{bmatrix}$

---

b) If I understand correctly $P \cdot \mathfrak{B} = \mathfrak{B}'$

This means $P = \mathfrak{B}' \cdot \mathfrak{B}^{-1}$

So we need to find the inverse of $\mathfrak{B}$. To do so, we set up an indentity matrix next to it, and then apply row operations to $\mathfrak{B}$ until we get the identity matrix. We apply the same row operations to the identity matrix, and that will give the inverse of $\mathfrak{B}$

We get https://matrixcalc.org/#%7B%7B1,2,3%7D,%7B2,1,1%7D,%7B0,2,1%7D%7D%5E%28-1%29

$\mathfrak{B}^{-1} = 1/7 \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 4 & -1 \\
    -2 & 1 & 5 \\
    4 & -2 & -3
\end{bmatrix}$

Thus $P = \mathfrak{B}' \cdot \mathfrak{B}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 2 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \cdot 1/7 \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 4 & -1 \\
    -2 & 1 & 5 \\
    4 & -2 & -3
\end{bmatrix} = 1/7 \begin{bmatrix}
    6 & -3 & -1 \\
    3 & 2 & -4 \\
    -2 & 1 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$

https://matrixcalc.org/#%7B%7B0,1,2%7D,%7B1,0,1%7D,%7B0,1,0%7D%7D*%7B%7B-1/7,4/7,-1/7%7D,%7B-2/7,1/7,5/7%7D,%7B4/7,-2/7,-3/7%7D%7D

Is this correct ? I'm quite new to the subject, so getting your feedback would be awesome. Thank you so much !